# Integration by parts of 3 vectorial functions

Tags: real-analysis, integration, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, vector-analysis

I am considering the following integral
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}  ( [\nabla   a ]\cdot \nabla b )   \Delta  c \ dx, 
$$
with $a, b$ and $c$ vanishing in the infinity.

By considering integration by parts, I was wondering if the following is true:

$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}  ( [\nabla   a ]\cdot \nabla b )   \Delta  c \ dx = - \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}  (\Delta a)b   \Delta c \ dx.
$$

**Do you have any idea if this could be true o if there exist a way to deal with it ?**

Comment: Are $a$, $b$ , and $c$ vector fields or scalar-valued functions defined over $\mathbb{R}^d$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but the following is true and follows from an application of the first of [Green's identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_identities), which are essentially some of the most straightforward generalization of integration by parts to higher dimensions:
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}(\nabla a\cdot\nabla b)\Delta c~\mathrm{d}x = -\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} b\nabla\cdot(\Delta c \nabla a)~\mathrm{d}x.$$
This can be expanded more via the product rule to get a $\Delta a$ term if you would like. Also, it is generally true then when integration by parts and related theorems are applied, one derivative is transfered from one function *onto all functions multiplying it*. In particular, the derivative removed from $b$ must be applied to both $a$ and $c$, so there must be some terms containing 3rd derivatives of $c$ after IBP has been applied.